# ASP.NET textbox textchange with same text input

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

My ASP.NET page has a text box (say TextBox1). I used  TextChanged event of  the TextBox1 to fill some other text boxes on the same page. Here is the problem:

- When the user has entered some text for the first time and lose the focus on the TextBox1, TextChanged event get fired and everything works as it should be.
- But if the user has entered the same input as the first time, TextChanged event doesn't get fired. (because no text changes between the postbacks)

I want to fire a server side event whether user input the same text or different text. So the rest of the page get updated in both cases. 
Any method or workaround for this ?

Code behind language is C#.

Edited: codes  added.

ASP page

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtClientNumber"  AutoPostBack="true"  
    runat="server" Width="100px"  onFocus="select()"
    OnTextChanged="txtClientNumber_TextChanged"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

C#

```
protected void txtClientNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 //txtName.Text = ...<get data from SQL Server >..
 //other codes
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Would be helpful if you add some code that shows what you have done :D

Comment: Is your TextBox control nested inside <form runat=server> ?

Comment: Yes, it is inside a form and TextChanged event works in normal situations.

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather broad, so the answer is a bit generic. For this purpose, use ASP.NET TextBox1 `OnTextChanged` event and set the property `AutoPostback="True"`.

Also, you can handle this event in client-side scripting by adding the attribute to `TextBox1` control: `TextBlock1.Attributes.Add("onblur","SomeJavascriptFunction()");`

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks, Tried with OnTextChanged and AutoPostback="True". Here is the thing, after user entering a text and page get updated, if the user needs to enter the same text again; OnTextChanged doesn't work. And this event should be handled on the sesrver

Comment: If Text didn't change then postback event won't trigger (it's quite logical, avoiding unnecessary server round-trip while nothing changed). You can implement Client-side processing using Javascript (onblur event will trigger even if text stay the same) as shown in my answer. Please check it accepted if satisfied, and should you have more questions, please post them separately. Best regards,

Comment: can you suggest an alternative method to fire a server side event whether textbox inputs similar or not. What event should call from the client side event handler. Because calling `TextChanged ` from JavaScript `onkeyup` or `onblur` doesn't work.

Comment: This comments thread is getting too lengthy. I have already answered your question. Should you have more questions, please post them separately. Best regards,